# PHP - $request->getPost('first_name')

Tags: php, zend-framework

```
public function process(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
{
     $this->first_name = $this->sanitize($request->getPost('first_name'));
....
}
```

My question is `$request` is an instance of class `zend_controller_request_abstract`, but getpost is a function defined in class `zend_controller_request_http` which extends `zend_controller_request_abstract`, so why does `$request` invoke `getPost()` directly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The type hint is just that, a hint. All it states is that `$request` must extend from `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`. It does *not* mean that `$request` is an instance of `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`.

In this particular case, `$request` is an instance of `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` which does implement `getPost()` and so you can call `$request->getPost()` with no problems. `$request` is also an instance of a class that extends from `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract` and so PHP allowed it to be passed into the `process` method in the first place.

Comment: To extend this answer: `instanceof` is useful in cases like this, it enables you to test for the actual type of the object - if you leave that out, you're code breaks for objects that don't support getPost().

Answer (score 0):

`getPost()` is not defined in `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract` and `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract` does not inherit this function by extension of any other class<strike>, so in short, that code you posted should throw some exception/error.</strike>

EDIT: It appears that in PHP, "If class or interface is specified as type hint then all its children or implementations are allowed too." This means that you can pass `Zend_Controller_Request_HTTP` to `process()` and it will work.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php